# ¿Cómo ingresar un array dentro de un form_params con la siguiente estructura para envío a una API (PHP)?

Tags: php, laravel, array, base-de-datos, api

Debo ingresa un array para un envío a una API dentro del form_params pero no se me ocurre como insertar dato por dato, para que me quedé esta estructura ejemplo:

```
$res = $this->client->request("POST", "{$this->endpoint}/properties", [
            "headers" => [
                "Authorization" => $this->auth
            ],
            "form_params" => [
              "codigo" => $obj->cod,
              "image_1" => "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/objeto/123312.jpg",
              "image_2" => "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/objeto/5454545.jpg"
]
```

Tengo este array gallery para ingresarlo en el form_params y que no quedé separado por **:** sino por **=>**

```
$gallery = [
    "image_1": "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/objeto/123312.jpg",
    "image_2": "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/objeto/5454545.jpg",
]
```

Comment: ¿Necesitas enviar un arreglo o una representación del mismo como cadena? Por favor edita tu pregunta para agregar más detalles y explicar exactamente los requerimientos y cómo lo estás enviando a la API.

Comment: Ya agregué un poco mas de Código para ser más especifico, debo guardar ese array $gallery con la estructura que puse en el primer código con ese key - value